# How to use FSharp.Data.JsonProvider dynamically?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm parsing JSON file using FSharp.Data.JsonProvider.
From http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html,
I have to declare type like this.

```
type Simple = JsonProvider<"path/to/simple/json.json">
```

But I want make the JsonProvider more flexible.
What I mean by flexible is to declare like below.

```
let x = "path/to/simple/json.json"
type Simple = JsonProvider<x>
```

So, the JsonProvider can deal with various json files, rather than only specific ones.

How can I do this? Or, there are other approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files have the same shape (ie same fields and field types), then you can use one as the type parameter, and then pass the others to `Parse`:

```
open System.IO

type Simple = JsonProvider<"file1.json">

let value1 = Simple.GetSample()
let value2 = Simple.Parse(File.ReadAllText "file2.json")
```

---

Edit: what if they don't have the same shape? Well, there are two cases.

If they have minor differences, like some fields that may be present or absent, or may be eg a string or a number, then you can make a sample file that is an array of samples and use `JsonProvider<"sample.json", SampleIsList = true>`. The generated type will accommodate for the differences using optional values.

If they are completely different, then JsonProvider simply isn't the right tool for the job. The purpose of JsonProvider is to give a nice API to read JSON when you know in advance what shape it's going to have. If you don't, then you should instead use a generic JSON parser with a document type, like System.Text.Json's JsonDocument or Newtonsoft.Json's JObject. I guess if you really want to keep using JsonProvider, you could also use the document type used by JsonProvider behind the scenes (called JsonValue).

Comment: What if they don't?

Comment: @JoshDredge Edited the answer for this case.